# Front Mic on Headset not working Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: sound, 22.04, microphone

My front mic is not working on my computer with my headset. I'm using a headset with to audio jacks (pink and green). It worked fine on Windows. Interestingly the mic on my webcam works fine. I can get the sound working on my headphone but not my mic. I've included a screenshot of my sound settings and system info below. My audio device codec is Realtek ALCS1200.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my headset's microphone working by replacing it with a headset that has better Linux support. As a rule of thumb it seems that if the OpenRazer software supports a headset it works well on Linux. The Razer Kraken x is the one I was having issues with and I replaced it the version 2 of the regular Razer Kraken headset.